# How do I manage multiple types of error states?

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, model-view-intent

Basically, I have a UI state data class as:

```kotlin
data class ServerState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = true,
    val fileData: MainData? = null,
    val error: Throwable? = null,
)
```

In my `ViewModel` there are two types of errors. First, is if the `client` is unreachable I show a full screen error with the text.

Now If someone tries to use another method it will also give an `Exception`, like for a single POST method. I want to show a `Toast` for that exception without passing context to the `ViewModel`.

For eg, this is a method in my `ViewModel` :-

```kotlin
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ServerState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun addFile(bytes: ByteArray) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when (
                val result: Result<Unit, Throwable> = runCatching {
                    client.add { rawFile["file_test"] = bytes }
                }
            ) {
                is Ok -> return@launch
                is Err -> emitException(result.error)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun emitException(e: Throwable) {
        val error = ExceptionHandler.mapException(e)
        _uiState.update { state -> state.copy(error = error) }
    }
```

I basically want to only show the major errors on full screen and minor method errors as `Toast`. Should I just add fields inside the state for it?

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For different UI behaviour just add another state. 2 different states will be handled at UI. 1 for full screen errors and another for Toasts.

Comment: `Toasts` are for only one time errors, so should I emit an event from the `Fragment` to clear the `toastError` in state after I have shown the toast?

Comment: in UI state you must have either "Init" or "Idle" state. So when you are done with handling toast/success/error you set state back to Idle.